# Edittext change border color with shape.xml

Tags: android, android-edittext

I make a shape.xml file under res -> drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#ff9900" />
</selector>
```

And then I use it on an `EditText`:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
    android:hint="@string/hint"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:background="@drawable/shape"/>
```

But the result is that it doesn't change the border color at all. Why, what's wrong?

Comment: Did my answer below solved your issue?

Comment: In case anyone else struggles with it too, You can't have "android:backgroundTint" set for this to work

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Why using `selector` as the root tag? `selector` is used for applying multiple alternate drawables for different states of the view, so in this case, there is no need for `selector`.

Try the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Background Color -->
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

    <!-- Border Color -->
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ff9900" />

    <!-- Round Corners -->
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

Also It's worth mentioning that all color entries support alpha channel as well, meaning that you can have transparent or semi-transparent colors. For example `#RRGGBBAA`.

Answer (score 13):

Step 1:Create a border.xml in Drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners
        android:radius="2dp"
        />
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"
        />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dip"
        android:color="#000" />
</shape>
```

Step 2:  Create a EditText in XML File

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:hint="Enter Email"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:singleLine="true" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     android:shape="rectangle">
     <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
     <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#ff9900" />
 </selector>
```

You have to remove `>` this from `selector` root tag, like below

```
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
```

As well as move your code to `shape` from `selector`.

Answer (score 1):

selector is used for applying multiple alternate drawables for different status of the view, so in this case, there is no need for selector

instead use shape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#ff9900" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

i use as following for over come this matter

edittext_style.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:thickness="0dp"
android:shape="rectangle">
<stroke android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#c8c8c8"/>
<corners android:radius="0dp" />
```

And applied as bellow

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editTextName"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"/>
```

try like this..

Answer (score 1):

Use this code on xml . i hope it will be work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:thickness="0dp"
           android:shape="rectangle">
      <stroke android:width="3dp"
             android:color="#4799E8"/>
      <corners android:radius="5dp" />
      <gradient
       android:startColor="#C8C8C8"
       android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
       android:type="linear"
       android:angle="270"/>
    </shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check below code may will help you,
Using stroke can make border in edit text and change it's color too as shown below...

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="10dp"
android:shape="rectangle">
<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="@color/secondary" />
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
```

Add this as background in to edit text.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `root tag` as `shape` instead of `selector` in your `shape.xml` file, and it will resolve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me:
Drwable->New->Drawable Resource File->create xml file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#e0e0e0" />
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#a4b0ba" />
    </shape>
```